# Calculating an integral with a seemingly complicated integrand

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I would like to calculate the following integral:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{1} \min (1,(u-1)^{n-1}(u-v)^{n-1}) dv $$
where $u$ is a constant taking values between $1$ and $2$ and $v$ is variable whose range is $(0,1)$.

It is pertinent to mention that $$ I= \int_{u-1}^{u} \min (1,t^{n-1}(u-1)^{n-1}) dt$$
when $1 \le t \le \frac{1}{u-1},$ the integrand reduces to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

At the first sight  one can see that our integral depends on $u$ and $n$ and so we need not restrict them in advance but  we should rather define  our integral as a function of $u$ and $n$. Now we can calculate it straightforwardly:

```
int[u_, n_] := Integrate[ Min[1, (u - 1)^(n - 1) (u - v)^(n - 1)], {v, 0, 1}]
```

e.g.

```
int[u,2]
```

[image]

Similarily we could define our integral with appropriate assumptions using another formula:

```
int2[u_, n_] := Integrate[ Min[1, t^(n - 1) (u - 1)^(n - 1)], {t, u - 1, u}, 
                           Assumptions -> n > 0 && 1 <= u <= 2]
```

yielding an equivalent function on the range of our interest, e.g.

```
int2[u, 2]
```

[image]

If we are to plot fast our functions we would better use numerical approach

```
nint[u_, n_] := NIntegrate[ Min[1, t^(n - 1) (u - 1)^(n - 1)], {t, u - 1, u}]
```

These are graphs of the integral for different values of $n$:

```
Plot[{ nint[u, 11/10], nint[u, 5/4], nint[u, GoldenRatio], nint[u, 2], 
       nint[u, 3], nint[u, 6]}, {u, 1, 2}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  PlotLegends -> {11/10, 5/4, GoldenRatio, 2, 3, 6}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

int[u_?(1 <= # <= 2 &), n_?NumericQ] :=
 NIntegrate[Min[1, (u - 1)^(n - 1) (u - v)^(n - 1)], {v, 0, 1}]

Plot3D[int[u, n], {u, 1, 2}, {n, -1, 5},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8],
 MaxRecursion -> 4,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {u, n, int})]
```

[image]